# Is there a way of changing regular expressions to a range of numbers in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I often need to create range of numbers in regular expressions. So e.g. '[2-3][0-9]' is range of numbers between 20-39. To double check my range, I normally use Linux command. For '[2-3][0-9]' the Linux command would be:

```
seq 1 40|egrep '[2-3][0-9]'
```

that prints all the numbers for me.

Is there anything similar to "seq 1 40|egrep" in Ruby on Rails that would print the numbers for me?

It would be quite handy, because I would prefer a nice GUI that I could create myself in Rails.

Comment: `(20..39)` http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Range.html

Answer (score 2):

You should write a unit test if you're concerned about it.

To test your regex quickly, use `irb` and write plain old Ruby:

```
irb(main):005:0> (1..40).map(&:to_s).grep(/[2-3][0-9]/)
=> ["20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39"]
```

That said, there are far better ways of producing ranges of numbers than filtering a whole sequence through a regular expression. That might, in fact, be the *worst* way of doing so.

```
(20..39).to_a
```

or

```
20.upto(39).to_a
```

or

```
20.times.map { |i| 20 + i }
```

And many, many, many more.  They're all *infinitely* better than using a regex to filter down a larger set of numbers to only those you need in order to build a simple sequential range.

Comment: Thank you. That answers my question. Is there a way of skipping that "defining sequence part", so I would write only [2-3][0-9] without defining range 1-40 and it would print all the numbers I need?

I want to develop a GUI, where when I type in [2-3][0-9] it will print all the numbers for me.

Comment: @user1489226 Which part are you talking about? I showed you three additional ways to skip the *entire* regular expression part. Regular expressions are not a suitable tool for this task, you shouldn't be using them here at all.

Comment: @meagar You don't seem to get the question at all. The OP wants the range of numbers to be generated automatically for a given regex.

Comment: @sawa Yes, and I'm trying to dissuade them from this course.

Comment: Yup. generating numbers automatically for a given regex. That's correct. so I type in [2-3][0-9] and it will print the range, without me telling Ruby that it has to be range between 1-40. Sorry, my fault, my question wasn't probably that clear.

Comment: @user1489226 you can use the first variant @meagar presented and build the regex dynamically with `Regexp.new(your_user_input)`

Comment: Can you be more specific p11y?

Comment: +1 for "there are far better ways of producing ranges of numbers than filtering a whole sequence through a regular expression"

Answer (score 2):

Using a regex to see if a number is in a certain range is code smell in the first place. You are taking the wrong approach (unless you are doing code golf or some other hacky thing). You should not try to build a regex that is intended to match a number in a certain range.

I recommend you not to use a regex for the checking part. Rather, just extract the number as is (using a regex), and see if it is within a range in a more direct way. Suppose you have a string `s`. Extract the number part of it using `(\d+)` within a regex . Then take out that part (if it is the first parenthesis in the regex, then it is `$1`), convert it into a number, and check if it fits in the range.

```
(20..39).cover?($1.to_i)
```